# numpy - translate an 2 dimensional array with a different x and y?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say there's an np array like this:

```
k = np.array([[13, 29],
              [17, 18],
              [19, 27]])
```

Now, I need to subtract 4 from column 1 and 8 from column 2 without looping with Numpy.

I tried `k - 4` but it seems to subtract even from axis 1.

Comment: column is not axis. Use numpy broadcasting: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_broadcasting.htm

Comment: Oh. My bad. I want column.

Comment: changed it to np array. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k - [4, 8]
```

Demo:

```
>>> >>> import numpy as np
>>> k = np.array([[13, 29],
                  [17, 18],
                  [19, 27]])
>>> k - [4, 8]
array([[ 9, 21],
       [13, 10],
       [15, 19]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just index the `column`, `row` or whatever you want (guide [by `scipy` here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing)) and then subtract whatever you want from each element in that section with `-=`:

```
>>> a
array([[13, 29],
       [17, 18],
       [19, 27]])
>>> a[:,0] -= 4
>>> a
array([[ 9, 29],
       [13, 18],
       [15, 27]])
>>> a[:,1] -= 8
>>> a
array([[ 9, 21],
       [13, 10],
       [15, 19]])
```